# How to let my application support iOS 4?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

I tested my application on 8GB iPod Touch using iOS 4.0(within multitask), it works. But when I change my original source code, and built it in the simulator. The application load, but nothing appear, it all dark. What I should do to solve the problem? I check the console, it didn't show any error msg. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

In the Simulator, check the Hardware->Device and Hardware->Version settings. Also, try setting a breakpoint in your code and stepping through it to see how far it gets.

Comment: Just did it. Same black screen.

Comment: @Tattat How far did it get when stepping through?